# toggle switch with text beside it

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a toggle switch from the w3c tutorial to line up with some text beside it.

this is the tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

and this is my code:

```
    <div class="sliderWrapper">
        <div><?php echo __('Postal Address');?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="data[SplashPage][firstname]">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderWrapper">
        <div><?php echo __('Postal Address');?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="data[SplashPage][lastname]">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
    </div>


.sliderWrapper{display: inline-block;margin:24px 24px 24px 24px;}
.sliderWrapper div{display: inline-block;line-height:60px;}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 28px;
}
/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}
/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {background-color: #1fb5ad;}
input:focus + .slider {box-shadow: 0 0 1px #1fb5ad;}
input:checked + .slider:before {-webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
-ms-transform: translateX(26px);transform: translateX(26px);}
```

Can anyone help me out with making the text be vertically aligned with the switch - been banging my head on the table of hours now :-(

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vfjgtaoh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the line:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to your switch class, this will vertically align the contents

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tzv75zvk/

Comment: thanks man... wow... so easy... hope you win the lottery or something - sending karma your way!

Answer (score 1):

Add `Vertical-align:middle;` property to label tag and remove `line-height` for the div

```
  .sliderWrapper div{
display: inline-block;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 54px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/vfjgtaoh/1/)